# Angular.js: How to change div width based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an input box which accepts the value for div width. 
Using angular.js, How can you change div's width based on user input?
I have implemented following code after referring this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/311chaos/vUUf4/4/

**Markup:**

```
 <input type="text" id="gcols" placeholder="Number of Columns" ng-model="cols" ng-change="flush()"/>

<div getWidth rowHeight=cols ng-repeat="div in divs">{{$index+1}} aaaaaa</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
var grid = angular.module('gridApp', []);

grid.controller('control', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    /* code for repeating divs based on input*/
    $scope.divs = new Array();
    $scope.create=function(){ //function invoked on button's ng-click
            var a = $scope.cols;
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                $scope.divs.push(a);
            }
            alert($scope.divs);
        };


}]);

grid.directive('getWidth', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            "rowHeight": '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            scope.$watch("rowHeight", function (value) {
                console.log(scope.rowHeight);
                $(element).css('width', scope.rowHeight + "px");
            }, false);
        }
    }
});

function appCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cols = 150;   //just using same input value to check if working


}
```

**UPDATE**
My ultimate goal is to set width of that div. When I call inline CSS like following I achieve what I want.

```
<div get-width row-height="{{cols}}" ng-repeat="div in divs" style="width:{{cols}}px">{{$index+1}} aaaaaa</div>
```

But this wouldn't be always efficient if number of divs goes high. So, again question remains, how to do this via angular script?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `ng-style="{width: cols + 'px'}"`, instead of style.

link to the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle

Comment: I've read many times that, often writing inline style is not a good practice. So if your element is gonna be repeated 100 times, it wouldn't be a good practice. That's why I'm avoiding writing inline style here. Would it be ok, if you're using ng-style?

Comment: Writing inline styles isn't usually a good practise but in this case this is the only thing that can be done to resize the element. As fro ng-style AFAIK it still add style="" but you can map scope variable to it so you could do something like ng-style="styles" and add the styles in the scope like: $scope.styles = {width: something + 'px'}

Comment: `{{cols}}` doesn't seem to work in newer Angular versions. If you're having this problem, try `(cols)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in yor angular syntax. You Should use

```
ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index"
```

Also you should use `attrs.$observe` instead of `$watch`.

Working demo (**updated**): http://jsfiddle.net/nidzix/UKHyL/40/

Comment: strange. That is working in fiddle. But not when brought into my code. When i don't write 'track by' it works fine, else does not.

Comment: Did you properly include angular library, controller and app name?

Comment: Yes definitely. Script is called properly, otherwise rest of code wouldn't have worked. Controller and app name is also fine. But I've placed directive after controller, is that fine?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. Fiddle is completely transparent, so there is no hidden code, and simple copy paste should be working. If you have other changes in your code they can have also impact to the result.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply. Thing is, I c/ped your fiddle as it is. So on my local, when I remove 'track by $index' part, it works fine. But when I remove the same part while on fiddle, it doesn't react. And vice-a-verse.