# Ng-style not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been trying to use `ng-style` all morning however it is not working as expected. In my directive I did something similar to this:

```
this.width = this.width+'px';
scope.myStyle = {width: this.width};
```

and in my html I have:

```
<div ng-style="myStyle" class="no-margin"
style="position:absolute;">
```

Comment: Does it get applied with wrong values? Not applied at all? Can you post the rest of the directive?

Comment: is your this doing the correct reference when assigning it to myStyle?

Comment: The this is setting the right values. It seems to be the syntax. The strange thing is that this code works:    <div ng-style="{{myStyle}}" class="no-margin" style="position:absolute;"> but I am unsure if I should use it because it shows an error in the HTML. That is pretty much the entirety of the code in that directive. There is also a watch function but is watching an unrelated variable.

Comment: I'm not sure an object is a correct usage for `ng-style`.. where have you seen this?

Comment: @OmriAharon here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Thanks. My guess is that it's the mash up of `this` and `scope`. Try `scope.width = this.width+'px'`, it probably does not recognize `this.width` in the view.

Comment: @OmriAharon never thought of that. With this I could cut out the ng-style and just use two way data binding in the style tag. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902822/angular-js-how-to-change-div-width-based-on-user-input

Comment: @YOU Thanks. Ill have a read

Answer (score 3):

`ng-style` should contain an object, so change your code to this:

```
this.width = this.width+'px';
scope.myStyle = {width: this.width, position:'absolute'};

<div ng-style="myStyle" class="no-margin">
```

Comment: What? Moving the "position" have no relation to the question

Answer (score 1):

The way should be:

`<div ng-style="{{ myStyle }}" class="no-margin">`

Reason being that the `{{ }}` is how AngularJs determine which is a variable or hard text.